# i do not want a page break before the longtable

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

i have a longtable at the end of my paper. the code is as follows

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
\LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
\footnotesize\bgroup\par\centering\@IEEEtabletopskipstrut{\normalfont\footnotesize #2}\\{\normalfont\footnotesize\scshape #3}\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\egroup\endgraf%
\@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace}%
\hss}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-9]
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{State Table for My Machine\label{design1}}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
a&b&c&d\\
\hline
1&2&3&4\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtable}{lccccccccccccccr}
\caption{State Table for My Machine}\label{design2}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{16}{l}{Table \ref{design} continued from previous page...}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
x               & xxxx            & x & x & x   & xx  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOO         \\ \hline
OOO             & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x0  & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 0   & 0    & PO          \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x1  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOP         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\ 
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

the longtable starts on a new page. i want it to start right under the two column text on the last page. how can this be done?

Comment: new page is starts because you change page format from two column to one (with `\onecolumn`. this command always start new page. this have nothing with long table.

Comment: how do you stop onecolumn from inserting a page break

Comment: you can't (as far as i know). try manually split your long table to two tables and put them to float `table*`, first at bottom of page, second on the top of the next page. for this you will need to load package `stfloats`.

Comment: thanks for giving me a good enough idea, if not a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

see, if the following solution can help you:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{State Table for My Machine\label{design1}}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\hline
a&b&c&d\\
\hline
1&2&3&4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]

    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{State Table for My Machine}
    \label{tab:design2_part-1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccccr}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
x               & xxxx            & x & x & x   & xx  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOO         \\ \hline
OOO             & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x0  & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 0   & 0    & PO          \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x1  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOP         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{16}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape (cont. on the next page}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\caption{State Table for My Machine (cont. from previous page)}
    \label{tab:design2_part-2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccccr}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial State} & R & C & sel & loc & \multicolumn{6}{c}{mol} & cre & con & r\_c & Final State \\
                &                 &   &   &     &     & 5  & 4  & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 &     &     &      &             \\
\hline
x               & xxxx            & x & x & x   & xx  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOO         \\ \hline
OOO             & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x0  & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 0   & 0    & PO          \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 0 & x   & x1  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0   & 0   & 0    & OOP         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 0 & 1 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 0 & x   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 00  & 0  & 1  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 01  &    &    & 0 & 1 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 1    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 0   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 0 & 1 & 0   & 1   & 1    & OOX         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 00  & 1  & 0  &   &   &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & XOO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 01  &    &    & 1 & 0 &   &   & 0   & 1   & 0    & OXO         \\
                & 0000            & 1 & 1 & 1   & 10  &    &    &   &   & 1 & 0 & 0   & 1   & 0    & OOX         \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```

it require manual splitting of your table into two parts.

[image]