# Content of table (longtable)overlapping with content after the table

Tags: longtable

[image][image][image]

[image]

My lower part of the longtable is overlapping with the content written below the table.
Second problem is the caption is not placed in the centre.
I have used the longtable package and table is 6 pages long[image]
[image]

[image]

```
       \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
         \usepackage{graphicx}
        % \usepackage{subfigure}
          \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{lipsum}
      \usepackage{tablefootnote}
     \usepackage{hyperref}
       \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
       \usepackage{csquotes}
         \usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
         \usepackage{stfloats}
         \usepackage{makecell,
            ltablex}    % new
        \keepXColumns
         % \raggedbottom
        % \usepackage{parskip} 
       \setcellgapes{3pt}
     \usepackage{enumitem}
         \usepackage{longtable}
         \usepackage{siunitx}

       % \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
         % \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
        \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
         %%
          %% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs

          \setlength\intextsep{\glueexpr\intextsep/2\relax}
           \AtBeginDocument{%
          \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
         \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

      % \maketitle
            \begin{document}  


         \section{ABCD}
        Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international
       standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29]
        is the latest video compression standards, which can also
       implement the intra-frame coding as image compression.
      JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard
        based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the
        image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are 
          dramatically quantized and compressed to realize
    data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is
     related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a
        large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation
      is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads 
       to some block artifacts [31] under low bit
            rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT.
        Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the 
     coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, 
      showing good local characteristics.
       Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international
        standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29]
     is the latest video compression standards, which can also
    implement the intra-frame coding as image compression.
       JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard
        based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the
     image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are dramatically 
       quantized and compressed to realize
       data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is
        related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a
     large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation
      is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads 
       to some block artifacts [31] under low bit
       rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT.
           Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the 
       coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input 
         image, showing good local characteristics


         \begin{center}
         \scriptsize
            \onecolumn
           \begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{8cm}|}

          \caption{ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}\\
        \hline
          \thead{\textbf{ABCD}} 
          & \thead{\textbf{ABC}}     
            & \thead{\textbf{ABCD}} 

            % &  \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{Loss}} \\\ 
        \specialcell{\textbf{Function}}}
          & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{ABCD} \\\ \specialcell{\textbf{ABCD}}} }   
        & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{ABCD} \\\ \& \specialcell{\textbf{ABCD}}} }  
           & \thead{\textbf{ABCD}}     \\
           % \textbf{First entryFirst entry} & \textbf{Second entryFirst entry} & 
        \textbf{Third entryFirst entry} & \textbf{Fourth entryFirst entry} \\
      \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
           {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline
          \thead{\textbf{Paper}} 
       & \thead{\textbf{DNN}}     
      & \thead{\textbf{Train/Test}} 

        % &  \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{Loss}} \\\ 
      \specialcell{\textbf{Function}}}
             & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{Performance} \\\ 
        \specialcell{\textbf{Measures}}} }   
        & \thead{\specialcell{\textbf{Complexity} \\\ \& 
          \specialcell{\textbf{Runtime}}} }  
           & \thead{\textbf{Critical Findings/Remarks}}     \\
          % \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & 
           \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
            \hline
         \endhead
      \hline 
           \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
         \hline
         \endlastfoot

        \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
           \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
                \item a
          \item a
          \end{itemize} 
           \end{minipage} 

            & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
           \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
               \item a
              \item a
              \item a
             \end{itemize}           
                \end{minipage} \\

           \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
          \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
             \item a
             \item a
            \end{itemize} 
                 \end{minipage} 

           & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
         \item a
            \item a
             \item a
           \end{itemize}           
           \end{minipage} \\




        \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
      \item a
         \item a
      \end{itemize} 
          \end{minipage} 

             & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
              \item a
             \item a
                 \item a
         \end{itemize}           
               \end{minipage} \\

            \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
             \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
              \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
           \item a
            \item a
            \end{itemize} 
             \end{minipage} 

           & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
         \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
         \item a
           \item a
             \item a
             \end{itemize}           
          \end{minipage} \\

         \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
          \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
             \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
               \item a
              \item a
           \end{itemize} 
              \end{minipage} 

            & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
           \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
             \item a
        \item a
            \item a
          \end{itemize}           
              \end{minipage} \\

         \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
           \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
             \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
            \item a
           \item a
        \end{itemize} 
               \end{minipage} 

          & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
          \item a
             \item a
             \item a
         \end{itemize}           
              \end{minipage} \\

        \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
        \item a
     \item a
          \end{itemize} 
          \end{minipage} 

         & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
         \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
         \item a
           \item a
          \item a
            \end{itemize}           
              \end{minipage} \\

          \textbf{vvvv}  2016 & A  & a & a &  
       \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
          \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.2cm]
          \item a
             \item a
          \end{itemize} 
            \end{minipage} 




         \hline

           \end{longtable}
         \twocolumn
         \end{center}


       \section{DCBA}
    Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international
                        standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29]
      is the latest video compression standards, which can also
   implement the intra-frame coding as image compression.
     JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard
         based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the
       image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are 
        dramatically quantized and compressed to realize
          data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is
        related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a
      large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation
      is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads 
            to some block artifacts [31] under low bit
     rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT.
    Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the 
         coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input 
    image, showing good local characteristics.
      Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international
      standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29]
      is the latest video compression standards, which can also
      implement the intra-frame coding as image compression.
     JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard
         based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the
        image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are 
     dramatically quantized and compressed to realize
         data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is
         related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a
      large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation
       is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads 
         to some block artifacts [31] under low bit
      rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT.
       Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the 
         coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, 
            showing good local characteristics.




               \end{document}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe and add that example code to your question.

Comment: From the screenshot I guess you use a twocolumn ocumentclass. If so, you will get an error message informing you thet `longtable` can not be used when in twocolumn mode. ("Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode."). In order to overcome this, add `\onecolumn` before the longtable and `\twocolumn` after the longtable. However, please be warned that these commands will add a pagebreak.

Comment: Yes exactly, the suggestion of using \onecolumn and \twocolumn solved the previous two problems, but again it rises two problems, as the table is starting from fresh page, Also after at the end of table, the complete page is left bank, the new text is starting from next page .......so how to fill that blank space after table

Comment: I put in an explicit test to check if the table is in two column mode and to give an error in that case. Why do you assume that if you scroll past the error that any output or any reasonable output will result? two column mode is not supported. As I commented on your previous question you should not get a blank page, if you do make an example and ask about that.

Comment: This is exactly what I already warned you about in my last comment. Without you providing a MWE, I can't give you a more spacific advice than splitting the table manually into multiple tabulars/tables (and using `ContinuedFloat` in order to prevent the table number from increasing.) (For an example, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410010/134144)

Comment: Sir I have added the code with 3 snapshots of output

Comment: Where is `\specialcell` defined? Please make your code compilable.

Comment: even if I define specialcell to do nothing still get errors: `! Missing { inserted.`

Comment: but I am not getting this error

Comment: if you are not getting the error you are presumably not using the document posted above but your original document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE is very unclear, so just a proposition based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409989/i-do-not-want-a-page-break-before-the-longtable/410010#410010) mentioned in @leandriis's comment, what you can do:

- Manually split table onto two parts. The first had to have `[b]` placement option, the second `[t]`. Between them had not to be any space. This action exploit `
- Insert table close to beginning of page so, that the first part of table will have sufficient space on page or make first part of table  small enough that will appear on the same page where is inserted.
- Use `tabularx` table
- For lists inside table set `itemize` by help of `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}                       %
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                 after=\end{minipage}                    % <---
                 }  }
```

- for rules use rules defined in the `booktabs` package and remove all vertical lines

An example of your table (as far as Was able decipher your table code) can be:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}   % changed
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}    % new
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                   % new
\setcellgapes{3pt}                          % new
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}                       %
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                 after=\end{minipage}                    % <---
                 }  }

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{ABCD}
Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29] is the latest video compression standards, which can also implement the intra-frame coding as image compression. JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are dramatically quantized and compressed to realize data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads to some block artifacts [31] under low bit rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT. Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, showing good local characteristics.
    \begin{table*}[b]
\footnotesize
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\caption{ABCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD}                  
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1cm} l p{1.5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm} X @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{ABC}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{Function}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{Critical Findings/Remarks}                     \\
    \midrule   
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Third entry First entry}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Fourth entry First entry}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
%%%% table body
\textbf{vvvv}  2016 
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}   
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
%    \hline
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
%    \hline
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on the next page}} \\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\footnotesize
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\caption[]{-- \textit{Continued from previous page}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1cm} l p{1.5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm} X @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{ABC}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{Function}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{Critical Findings/Remarks}                     \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Third entry First entry}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Fourth entry First entry}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
%%%% table body
\textbf{vvvv}  2016
    & B & C & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item a
                \item a
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item a
                    \item a
                    \item a
                        \end{itemize}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}

% this paragraph are moved after table that the first part of table has enough space page where it is inserted
Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29] is the latest video compression standards, which can also implement the intra-frame coding as image compression. JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are dramatically quantized and compressed to realize data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads to some block artifacts [31] under low bit rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT. Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, showing good local characteristics.

\section{DCBA}
Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29] is the latest video compression standards, which can also implement the intra-frame coding as image compression. JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are dramatically quantized and compressed to realize data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads to some block artifacts [31] under low bit rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT. Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, showing good local characteristics.

Currently, JPEG and JPEG2000 [28] are the international standards for image compression, and h. 265/HEVC [29] is the latest video compression standards, which can also implement the intra-frame coding as image compression. JPEG is the earliest proposed image compression standard based on discrete cosine transform (DCT) [30]. After the image is decomposed by DCT, the high-frequency coefficients are dramatically quantized and compressed to realize data compression. However, each coefficient after DCT is related to all the pixels of the whole image; thus, it requires a large amount of computation. Therefore, block segmentation is carried out before implementing the subsequent compression, which leads to some block artifacts [31] under low bit rate. Compared with JPEG, JPEG2000 is based on DWT. Because the length of the base function of the DWT is variable, the coefficients after DWT only reflect some local features of the input image, showing good local characteristics.
   \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate text area border)

Comment: Sir, I copied the code provided and ran, and my output seems different than this,,as I have updated above as an image

Comment: @DiptiMishra, as far as I see, you obtain the same result. The difference in the results shown is that in my answer not the whole page is shown, but only the relevant part. What is the problem?

Comment: I dont want this red border and lines below third entry fourth entry. AlsoI am not able to understand the code.. Can you please write comment lines after each thing

Comment: @DiptiMishra: The red lines are caused by the `showframe` package. Remove the three lines immediately after `%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!` to remove them. To remove the horizontal lines below "First entry"  and "fourth entry", remove `\cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}`.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: @DiptiMishra, sometimes helps if you read comments in code. :-). Also, if you provide a MWE with all your style/new-command definitions in preamble of the your question, this helps to people here in effort to helping you. Your table (columns) headers are not clear, so used in my answer are based on guessing :-(. If answer solve your problme, you may consider to accept it.

Comment: Sir, How to close these borders of the table,, snapshot is attached

Comment: @DiptiMishra, which borders? Red one, which show page layout? Just remove its code from preamble. They are clearly indicated with comment.  Anyway, I will remove them from code asap but left on images.

Comment: @DiptiMishra: Do you mean the little gaps at the corners of the table? If you wish to keep the vertical lines, use `\hline` instead of `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. The last three commands are from  the `booktabs` package and are designed to be used without vertical lines.

Comment: No I am talking of small gaps and voids at 4 corners of table, please see snap

Comment: No, I am talking of small gaps and voids at 4 corners of the table, please see the snap. Also facing 2one more problems, I have table of approx 8 pages, So all the text which is written after the table has gone above the table. Although I have inserted a table in the middle of my complete document of 24 pages, the table is coming in the last, after the references. Thirdly, the last page of the table is having blank space above the table, and below also. Please help

Comment: @DiptiMishra, see comments of  leandriis. I strongly encourage you to not use vertical lines. Without them tables looks more "professional"/ aesthetic. However, if persist with them, than remove `booktabs` package` and replace all rules (top, mid and bottom) with `\hline`.