# Table footnote not showing up at all in bottom

Tags: footnotes

My code is here, The table here contains many footnote, but it does not appear at the bottom of page. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
 \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{tablefootnote}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[demo,
             export]{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{stfloats}
 \usepackage{makecell,
             ltablex}    % new
 \usepackage{makecell, tabularx}   % changed
 \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}    % new
 \renewcommand\theadgape{}                   % new
 \setcellgapes{3pt}                          % new
 \usepackage{siunitx}

 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}                       %
 \AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
 \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                   leftmargin=*,
                   label=\textbullet,
                   before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
                   after=\end{minipage}                    % <---
                   }  }
 \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
 \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}
 %%%
 }

 \usepackage{float}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{table*}[htbp]
     \scriptsize
     \setcellgapes{3pt}
     \makegapedcells
     \caption{ABCD}                  
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{} p{1cm}| l| p{1.5cm}| p{3cm} |p{2cm}| X @{}|}
     \hline
 \thead{Paper}
     & \thead{DNN}
       & \thead{Train/Test}
         & \thead{\specialcell{Performance} \\\ \specialcell{Measures}}
     & \thead{\specialcell{Complexity} \\\ \specialcell{Runtime}}
       & \thead{Critical Findings/Remarks}                     \\
       \hline
       \hline

      \textbf{A}  2016 &  A  & A (PEIRVM)\footnote{https://groups.csail.mit.edu/vision/TinyImages}         
   & A
        & \begin{itemize}
      \item a
      \item a
         \end{itemize} 
   &  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \item a
    \item a
      \end{itemize} \\
   \hline
 \textbf{A}  2019 & A  & Camelyon 16\footnote{https://camelyon16.grand-challenge.org/}, Tupac 
   16\footnote{http://tupac.tue-image.nl/node/3}, Rectum 
    \footnote{https://www.pathologyoutlines.com/topic/colonhistology.html}  & a   & \begin{itemize}
     \item a
   \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
   \item a
   \item a
   \end{itemize}\\
   \hline
   \textbf{A}  2020 & A &a    &  a & \begin{itemize}
                                      item a
                                      \item a
                                      \end{itemize} 
     & \begin{itemize}
       \item a
       \item a
       \item a\footnote{https://bellard.org/bpg/}
       \end{itemize} \\
   %%%% table body
       \hline
    \end{tabularx}
         \end{table*}
       \end{document}
```

**Edit:** My result of tests of the Zarko's solutions:

[image]

After second edit:

[image]

After third edit:

[image]

Comment: How or where is `\specialcell` defined?

Comment: iTS A PART OF SOME OTHER PACKAGE, i SUPPOSE. i HAVE ALSO ATTACHED THE OUTPUT

Comment: `\spacialcell` in not part of any package that you load in the preamble of your example code. If must be defined somewhere else. Does your original document contain something like `\newcommand{\specialcell}...`?

Comment: No, it is not. I sow almost the same question few days ago, unfortunately I can't find it now ...

Comment: Did you already have a look at [Footnotes in tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/134144) and its answers?

Comment: @DiptiMishra - What do you hope to get out shouting at people by WRITING A COMMENT THAT USES ONLY UPPERCASE LETTERS?

Comment: Sorry sir, my caps lock was on, I didnt mean that, i was not shouting at all, just wanted help

Comment: Yes I tried a lot through various resources through Web

Comment: Now I have added this               \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}
                   %%%
}

Comment: I took liberty and edit you question. I move result of your test of my code and the end of your question. Please check again, if you get the same result for the third version of my answer as is now show in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may serve as starting point. You need to enclose table in `minipage` (MWE is partly based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544562/content-of-table-longtableoverlapping-with-content-after-the-table/544606#544606)):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}                       %
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},  
                 after=\end{minipage}                     
                 }  }

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[t]
\caption{ABCD}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    % <--- 
\footnotesize
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1cm} l p{2cm} p{3cm} p{3cm} X @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{ABC}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{ABCDE}
    & \thead{Function}
    & \thead{ABCD}
    & \thead{Critical Findings/Remarks}                     \\
    \midrule
%%%% table body
\textbf{A}  2016
    & A
        &   Camelyon 16\footnote{https://camelyon16.grand-challenge.org/},

            Tupac 16\footnote{http://tupac.tue-image.nl/node/3},

            Rectum \footnote{https://www.pathologyoutlines.com/topic/colonhistology.html}
            & B &   \begin{itemize}
                \item aaa
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item aaa
                    \item bbb
                        \end{itemize}\\
    \midrule
\textbf{B}  2020 
    & C & D & D &   \begin{itemize}
                \item aaa
                \item bbb
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item aaa
                    \item bbb
                    \item ccc \footnotemark[4]
                        \end{itemize}       \\    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\footnotetext[4]{https://bellard.org/bpg/} % <====
    \end{minipage}  % <---
    \end{table*}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: don't use `ltablex`, it is (as `longtable`) prohibited in two columns documents.

**Edit (1):** added is example of use of the `\footnote` in lists nested in tables.

**Edit (2):** Sorry, at my first edit of answer I didn't load complete version of edited MWE where is missed the code line with `\footnotetext[4]{https://bellard.org/bpg/}` before `\end{minipage}`. Now corrected and this line marked by `% <====`.

**Edit (3):** Sorry, but last day was my very badd day ... yes, after `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` is missed code line `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}`. Now is added.

Comment: Sir, my last footnote not showing, i.e. d, and its showing as complete URL in table itself, like my posted snap...Second problem is, footnotes are not appearing at bottom last of the page, rather ist appeared at middle. Please help

Comment: and why is is written like \footnotemark[4]

Comment: snapshot is attached above

Comment: @DiptiMishra, `[4]` is identification to which `\footnotemark` belong `\footnotetext` and by which letter they are identified  (by forth letter in alphabet , i.e by *d*).

Comment: but in my document the output is not looking like same what is shown here

Comment: @DiptiMishra, you are right. I didn't upload the last version of my MWE, so the code line `\footnodetext[4]{...}` is missed in it. Now is corrected. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DiptiMishra, please (i) edit your question and make your MWE compilable that other people can test it, (ii) if add result of my MWE to your question, please clearly describe this in question and add it on the end of question. Now is not clear what present image on the top of your question.

Comment: Edited that, but again something else is missing as now , footnote reference is missing in text (d) as you can see in snapshot. Also please suggest a way to display these footnotes at the bottom of the page, not at the middle.

Comment: @DiptiMishra, corrected. See 3rd edit ...

Comment: No, again the same problem, I hope you get out of your problems. See snap